# Why would one need to verify a download | SHA-256 checksum

Tags: cryptography, sha

So, recently when downloading an update, I saw the option that stated:
'Download and verify the file SHA-256 checksum.'.

My question(s):

1. What is the purpose of this?
2. How is it beneficial(if question 1 doesn't answer this) ?
3. Who would need to make use of this ?
4. Can you point me to some literature in this regard ?

Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on how the data and the hash are delivered to the user. It provides at least integrity, but it can also provide authenticity to some extent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [security.se] is much better suited for this type of question.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm in agreement. Can I close the topic myself ? As I will move it over to IS.

Comment: You've already received an answer that contains the two most important (probably the only valid points) about this issue. There is no need to move the question to another site. In order to move it to a site where there is no standard migration path (as in this case), you would have to flag for moderator attention and ask for migration. This takes a long time. Note that you can start flagging when you have at least 15 reputation.

Comment: I won't flag it myself, because it is already answered in [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/82716/45523). After migration it would probably just be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, thanks man. I appreciate the feedback. I checked the article and it answered my question to a T. Thank you. Answer below was marked correct as it got the gist of my question answered.

Comment: for what it's worth, I was wondering this same thing and instinctively went to SO to search for an answer, happy to find it exactly where I expected. upvoting the question.  In retrospect, maybe SE it the better place to search so the correct site comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose is to ensure the integrity of the file arrived exactly as it was intended.

2 reasons I am aware of:
A) file was not corrupt in transit,
B) file was not intercepted and modified in transit, having said that if someone is able to modify the download in transit then modifying the checksum in transit should not be a problem for them either.

Only situation I can imagine B would be useful is if the downloads are transmitted over HTTP whereas the SHA has was delivered over HTTPS.

Comment: Mirrors. Usually the SHA-256 hash is provided on a web-page of the originating server.

Comment: So it's really not a protection against hackers at all (which is what I thought it was) - more just a protection against corrupted downloads.  (SInce a hacker could modify the webpage if they altered the download link etc.)  Since we're mostly downloading DMG's and ZIP files, I've assumed any corruption would immediately show up when trying to extract - before executing the software.